# Issue when running wget inside a bash script with an url stored in a variable

Tags: wget

I'm having the following bash script:

```
URL=`grep -E -m 1 -o "<ExportCatalogResult>(.*)</ExportCatalogResult>" costa_export.xml| sed -e 's,.*<ExportCatalogResult>\([^<]*\)</ExportCatalogResult>.*,\1,g'` &&
echo $URL 
echo -n $url > url.txt &&
wget $(cat url.txt | tr -d " \t\n\r") -O price.zip
```

The problem is that, when running the script, wget is always downloading an empty file:

```
http://training.******.net/WAWS_1_9/Catalog/price.zip //echo $URL

Resolving training.******.net (training.*******.net)... 194.**.***.90, 194.**.***.90

Connecting to training.******.net (training.*****.net)|194.**.***.90|:80... connected.

HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 204 Still exporting

Length: 0

Saving to: ‘price.zip’

[ <=>                                                ] 0           --.-K/s   in 0s
```

However, the url that is echoed is a valid one  (running a wget with that url in the command line will download the zip package).

Why is this happening?

Comment: The obvious suspect is that the script URL gets an invisible character included (a newline or a space, for example) that you don't put there when you try it on the command line.

Comment: @CalleDybedahl and how could I know that. I updated the script to remove all whitespace and newline but without success...

Comment: One way is to print it with delimiters. `echo "<$URL>"`, or so, and see that it looks like you expect. The other is to print it to a file and then check the file with an editor to make sure the content is exactly what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems jump out at me here:

1. You haven't quoted your variables, so the shell is potentially mangling the values. I'll give you an alternative suggestion for your script, which draws upon the [removal of whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3352015).
2. You're processing XML with Regular Expressions. This will work for now, but be aware that it may well break in the future when something unexpected changes.

Code follows

```
#!/bin/bash

# ...

# Not even going to attempt to reduce this without seeing your XML
url=$(grep -E -m 1 -o "<ExportCatalogResult>(.*)</ExportCatalogResult>" costa_export.xml| sed -e 's,.*<ExportCatalogResult>\([^<]*\)</ExportCatalogResult>.*,\1,g')

# Debug
echo "raw: $url" >&2

# Strip leading and trailing whitespace
url="${url#"${url%%[![:space:]]*}"}"   # remove leading whitespace
url="${url%"${url##*[![:space:]]}"}"   # remove trailing whitespace

# More debug
echo "now: $url" >&2

# Save the URL
echo -n "$url" > url.txt

# Retrieve the URL contents
wget -O price.zip "$url"
```

Answer (score 1):

My way of Debugging this situation:

1. Which shell is executing your script ? Put the "**#!**" to the shell where it works (you said it works in your command-line)
2. If you change your script to Directly execute "wget **URL**", where **URL is hardcoded** to the output $URL, will it get the file ?
3. If you take **some other URL** from some other website , will it work ?
4. If you have access to the website , can you check the **access logs & error logs** of the web server ?
5. What is **exit status** of wget ? It will help to know what "echo $?" shows, to compare with http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Exit-Status